# Sudden "access denied" when committing to SVN from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, authorization, svnkit

I am using Eclipse Kepler, build ID 4.3.2.M20140221-1700 with SVNKit1.8.3. So far, this has worked fine.

Due to a corrupted `.project` file, I had to delete and re-import the project I'm working on into Eclipse, and since then, I am unable to commit to the SVN repository (SVN-Eclipse throws an `SVNConnectorException`, due to an `SVNAuthenticationException`; this is all the information that I have in Eclipse's logs and messages).

I can commit the same files to the same repository from the CLI and from TortoiseSVN without an problems. Within Eclipse, I can do all other SVN operations on the repository (which all use the exact same authentication data). Nothing was changed on the side of the SVN server.

I have tried de-installing and re-installing SVN-Eclipse, but keep running into the same problem.

Any helpful tips are welcome - from the data I have I cannot think of anything else to try.

Comment: Did my answer help you in 2014? Please, upvote and accept it then. :)

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure that you enter the correct URL: [path-based access rules in Subversion 1.7+ are parsed *case-sensitively*](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#case-sensitive-authz).
- If the URL enter is correct, then I suggest checking [Subversion log (i.e. Apache HTTP Server access log)](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/serverconfig/httpd/#svn.serverconfig.httpd.extra.logging). It may have clues on why you observe such behavior.

Comment: Thanks. As to your first point: the paths are unchanged (and like I said, repo-browsing, update, diff, etc. all use the exact same credentials and have no issues - neither had commit until after I had to re-import the project).

As to your second point: I don't have log-viewing access to the SVN server (and our IT staff has gone home for the day already), but like I mentioned, the problem only happens inside Eclipse (my non-eclipse clients using the same credentials works fine for all operations.)

Comment: @conzo77 show the exact and complete wording of the error. I still strongly suggest verifying the URL you've entered in Eclipse character by character. E.g. checkout a new working copy using 100% correct URL of the project and see if you get the same error.